# Python pyqt5 Reminder and Notepad Launcher

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have met with a problem on Python. I tried to create a Reminder and Notepad.There is no troubles with Reminder, but the notepad is quite hard. I use QPlainTextEdit to open .txt files, save notes and so on.The problem is that it does not work. You may start looking from the class fileeki, cause notepad starts there. My interface is written in QTdesigner and the file's type is ui. I use mainwindow which is convertod to .py from .ui , but other widgets are as usual in .ui .Please help me!!!

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QStatusBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QFileDialog, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from ui_filebir import Ui_MainWindow
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time
import sqlite3
import easygui 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


class MyWidget(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.resize(520, 300)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.notepad_run)
        self.re_but.clicked.connect(self.reminder_run)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.dbrun)
        self.rate = self.lineEdit.text()


    def dbrun(self):
        pass
        #con = sql.connect('dbrate.db')
        #cur = con.cursor()
        #cur.execute(query)
        #res = cur.execute(query)
        #con.commit()
        #con.close()


    def notepad_run(self):
        self.uineweki = fileeki()
        self.uineweki.show()
        self.close()

    def reminder_run(self):
        self.ui_fileush = fileush()
        self.ui_fileush.show()
        self.close()


class fileeki(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('uineweki.ui', self)

        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit()

        self.path = None

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.opening_run)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.saving_run)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.saveac)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.bak)

    def dialog_critical(self, s):
        dlg = QMessageBox(self)
        dlg.setText(s)
        dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        dlg.show()

    def opening_run(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)")

        if path:
            try:
                with open(path, 'rU') as f:
                    text = f.read()

            except Exception as e:
                self.dialog_critical(str(e))

            else:
                self.path = path
                self.editor.setPlainText(text)

    def saving_run(self):
        if self.path is None:

            return self.saveac()

        self._save_to_path(self.path)

    def saveac(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)")

        if not path:

            return

        self._save_to_path(self.path)

    def _save_to_path(self, path):
        text = self.editor.toPlainText()
        try:
            with open(path, 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)

        except Exception as e:
            self.dialog_critical(str(e))

        else:
            self.path = path
            self.update_title()

    def new_run(self):
        pass

    def bak(self):
        self.close()
        self.nazad = MyWidget()
        self.nazad.show()


class fileush(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi('ui_fileush.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.running)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.bakk)

    def running(self):
        toaster = ToastNotifier()

        self.first_input = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.second_input = self.lineEdit_2.text()

        t = time.sleep(int(self.first_input))
        toaster.show_toast(self.second_input)


    def bakk(self):
        self.close()
        self.nazad = MyWidget()
        self.nazad.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

## my github https://github.com/iMAGA07/yandexProj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the text to the new QPlainTextEdit you created, but you should actually point it to the one you use in the gui:

```
def opening_run(self):
    # ...
        else:
            self.path = path
            # change this
            # self.editor.setPlainText(text)
            # to this
            self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(text)
```

That `self.plainTextEdit` is the object you created in designer (the object names are listed in the object inspector tree). Obviously, this also means that you don't need to create `self.editor` in the first place.

Comment: wow, thanks for your answer, but i have another problem with the program. When i want to open file it shows window with the text 'expected string or bytes-like object not tuple' and if saving 'expected string or bytes-like object not NoneType'

Comment: I tested your code without any problem, check if you changed the arguments of the static QFileDialog methods you're using with the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName).

Comment: excuse me, did you open my project by GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I used the zip download from the master.

Comment: If you get a different problem, it's better to create a new question. Take that opportunity to edit your example to make it more like a [minimal reproducible one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which could potentially help you to understand the source of the problem in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you, link to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135406/saving-text-from-qplaintextedit-by-qfiledialog-and-creating-txt-file

Comment: If this answer helped you, remember to mark it as accepted (the check button on the left of it). About that new question, sorry but I'll be blunt: I will not help you until you provide **really minimal and reproducible** examples: that question has even more code than this one. Take your time, trim it down (or even write a new example to even help yourself to understand what is not working) and make it as *self contained* as possible. You can't expect everybody is willing to download and inspect all your code if you're not the first one to make good efforts to understand it in the first place.